# Data Explorer (SEDE) Auto-Login that redirects back to original target page

Tags: script, data-explorer

#### About:

When you visit SEDE, this userscript:

1. Automatically logs in you in if needed. (You must have a valid SEDE login).
2. Redirects back to the original desired page like a good login system should.

#### Features:

- Stores the login credentials in the browser, encrypted.
- When you first run the script, it will ask for (A) a random seed, and (B) your username and password.
- Open-source and on GitHub.

#### Screenshot:

(Click for larger image.)
        [image: Auto Login sequence][image: Auto login logo]

#### Reference:

- [SEDE login redirects to front page rather than returning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256042/sede-login-redirects-to-front-page-rather-than-returning)
- [Automatic logging into Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109649/automatic-logging-into-data-explorer)
- [Are user accounts on data.stackexchange.com and Stack Exchange two different entities?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115131/are-user-accounts-on-data-stackexchange-com-and-stack-exchange-two-different-ent)

#### Platform:

This is a userscript that runs in your browser.  It requires a userscript extension like *Tampermonkey* or *Violentmonkey*.

#### Install button: <kbd>[Install from GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%20Data%20Explorer%20(SEDE)%20auto%20login.user.js)</kbd>

#### Code:

The code is [on GitHub, in the BrockA/SE-misc repository](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Stack%20Exchange%20Data%20Explorer%20(SEDE)%20auto%20login.user.js).

Post bug reports and pull requests there. <sup><sub>(Or below if you don't do GitHub.)</sub></sup>

**Known issues:**

1. **Only set up for Stack Exchange Authentication.**  If you use Google or something else, the script will probably have to be modified (Which I can do for a sufficient fee (or pull request)).
2. Will not support Greasemonkey 4+. Use Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey, or equivalent.

Comment: Okay works, but ■ note that if you enter your username/password, it will be stored in plain text in your Greasemonkey database. Normally only the plugin can access this so you're safe; however some browser (e.g. qutebrowser) stores it in localStorage of the site, so an extremely targeted attack (also requires XSS vulnerability on SO to access localStorage, I think. Not sure if stacksnippets count) might be able to get your password. Be careful. Otherwise they're stored in in hard drive anyway. ■ The "encryption key" is only for obfuscation, not "real encryption". ■ I think the script should...

Comment: ... only try to prompt the user when the "log in with SO" button is clicked then it's not already logged in SE. Since the cookie timeout (presumably) is much larger on SE than on data.SE, most of the time clicking the "login with SO" button will be sufficient to login, so the password never needs to be used at all. (in that case just type random strings for the username/password works.)